# Will supply drops stop if I liberate nearby colonies?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

One of my party members mentioned that colonies may stop receiving supply drops if we liberate them by

> Destroying the colony's flame clock

Does this mean if I liberate a colony I won't be able to find supply drops in the nearby area anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on personal experience, supply drops will still spawn even after liberating the colonies in the area.

From a lore perspective, the number of colonies you encounter is just a small fraction of how many colonies actually exist. So while only a handful of colonies are liberated during the story, there are still un-liberated colonies that might be within the area